# Array Combine function with duplicated values (preserved keys)

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, one array in the code is representing title(simple string), and the other one is email(simple string also). This two arrays will always be the same, and I need to create key value pairs of them.

```
[
    $email => $title
]
```

So, my $email array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test@test.com
    [1] => test@test.com
    [2] => test@test.com
)
```

And my $tile array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Distributor
    [1] => Internal
    [2] => Agency
)
```

So I need this two arrays to be:

```
Array
(
    [test@test.com] => Distributor
    [test@test.com] => Internal
    [test@test.com] => Agency
)
```

In the beginning I was using the array_combine, but when this duplicated email values occurred my code broke. I could not find good solution at this point. I tried to manipulate the arrays with this function from the php manual:

```
function array_combine_($keys, $values)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($keys as $i => $k) {
        $result[$k][] = $values[$i];
    }
    array_walk($result, create_function('&$v', '$v = (count($v) == 1)? array_pop($v): $v;'));
    return    $result;
}
```

But it is deprecated and it does not work. I appreciate any help with this issue.

Comment: You cannot have an array with duplicated keys.

Comment: Why not `[Distributor] => test@test.com` ???  Seems a better format.

Comment: The array you're trying to create is simply not possible. It doesn't matter what method you try to use, array keys have to be unique.

Comment: You could make the value an array: `["test@test.com" => ["Distributor", "Internal", "Agency"]]`. In fact, that seems to be what you're doing in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: The only thing that's deprecated is `create_function`, but you can do the same thing with an anonymous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot have multiple of the same key in an associative array.

You can use the values as the keys and keys as values

```
$keys = ['test@test.com','test@test.com','test@test.com'];
$values = ['Distributor','Internal','Agency'];
$res = array_combine($values, $keys);
```

Output

```
Array
(
 [Distributor] => test@test.com
 [Internal] => test@test.com
 [Agency] => test@test.com
)
```

Or you can add something to make them unique like the index number and later on remove that index number

```
$keys = ['test@test.com','test@test.com','test@test.com'];
$values = ['Distributor','Internal','Agency'];
$res = [];
array_walk($keys, function($v, $k) use ($values, &$res){
  $res[$v."-".$k] = $values[$k];
});
```

Output

```
Array
(
 [test@test.com-0] => Distributor
 [test@test.com-1] => Internal
 [test@test.com-2] => Agency
)
```

Here you can remove the -Index to use them.